# Run code after ValueEventLister has retrieved the firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, asynchronous, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

Im using firebase authUI in order to login/register users in my app, the thing is that I want to know when the user registers for the 1st time and when he is a returning user who just logs in. I thought that it would be a good idea to "see" in my DB if the current UID exists, if it is the user exists and if it doesnt exists its a new user.

Below is the code which works fine but the the ValueEventLister "call" is asynchronous and when it checks for the user UID it already exists because it was just written in DB but in reality its a new user. How should I modify my code in order to work as expected?

```
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {

            final FirebaseUser signedUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

            ValueEventListener postListener = new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: " + dataSnapshot.child(getString(R.string.users)).child(signedUser.getUid()).exists());
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    // Getting Post failed, log a message
                    Log.w(TAG, "loadPost:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
                }
            };

            mDatabase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(postListener);


//            uid = setNullToDefaultValue(signedUser.getUid());
//            displayName = setNullToDefaultValue(signedUser.getDisplayName());
//            email = setNullToDefaultValue(signedUser.getEmail());
//            photoUrl = setNullToDefaultValue(signedUser.getPhotoUrl().toString());
//            provider = setNullToDefaultValue(signedUser.getProviderId());
//            phoneNumber = setNullToDefaultValue(signedUser.getPhoneNumber());
//
//            Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult: User Signed In!");
//            User mUser = new User(uid, displayName, email, photoUrl, provider, phoneNumber);
//            Map<String, Object> userMap = mUser.toMap();
//            mDatabase.child(getString(R.string.users)).child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).updateChildren(userMap);
        }
    }
```

I commented to code in order to see if the "check" works and it does.

Comment: I dont understand. Why should you create new user after new user is created?

Answer (score 0):

The `FirebaseAuth` class has separate methods for creating an account and for signing into an account. You can just add an `onCompleteListener` to the method to execute your code whenever the respective method is called. For example, for authentication via email, you can use the following :-

```
 mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

        }
    });
```

and

```
mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
       @Override
       public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

       }
   });
```

Besides these, if your user stays signed in between app sessions, then you can simply use auth state listeners.